# Why does setting a div's position to "fixed" mess up the width of the element itself?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, fixed

I have a message box that I want to stay at the bottom of the screen, rather than the page for scrolling purposes.

[image]

The fixed position seems to be the way to do it, but the problem is when I set the message box position to fixed it makes it wider for some reason.

[image]

The HTML body looks like this:

```
<div class="container message-area">
    <div id="user-messages">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container message-box-area">
    <form class="message-box-form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message-box" name="message-box">
        <button type="submit" onclick="sendMessage()" hidden />
    </form>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/* messages */

.message-area {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  background-color: orange;
}

.user-message {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.user-message::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.user-message img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.user-message img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.time-right {
  float: right;
  color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
}

/* message box */

.message-box-area {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.message-box-form {
 /* display: flex;
 bottom: 0%; */
}

.message-box {
 background-color: red;
}
```

My understanding of fixed is it sets the length to the body or something? How can I make it work?

Comment: ````position: fixed```` will be positioned relative to the viewport/window itself, not the ````<body>````. And I guess ````position: absolute```` doesn't work in your case if you want it to stay at the bottom when the other content scrolls. So if you want it to be the same width as the body, then the easiest way would be to simply set the same ````max-width```` on the fixed element.

Comment: @Snor I can set max-width: 760px to match it, thanks. Problem now is the message-box input won't shrink - but that might be easy to solve.

Comment: specifically, the width of .message-box-area container won't change like the .message-area container does.

Answer (score 1):

Just used position: sticky. That's the way to go